# WindowInsets returns always 0 when the screen is rotating forcibly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager, android-11, windowinsets

When i got the screen size of width and height, i used to use the `WindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)` before and this is the whole code below.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
usableWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

But **in Android 11**, that `getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)` is deprecated. 
so i found `WindowInsets' and it worked well when the screen is being showing. 
and it also worked well when the screen is from portrait to portrait or landscape to landscape.  
but there is a problem. when i rotate the screen from portrait to landscape forcibly, **WindowInsets** can't get the accurate current size of the display. 
in detail, it's 3 step.

**1. Start the app.** 
 
**2. As soon as the app start, the screen rotates from portrait to landscape forcibly.** 
**3. WindowInsets can't get the `Insets.right` and `Insets.left`.**

this the the whole code to get the display size.

```
private static int getDisplaySize(WindowManager wm, boolean wantWidth) {
    int usableHeight = 0;
    int usableWidth = 0;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        WindowMetrics metrics = wm.getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        WindowInsets windowInsets = metrics.getWindowInsets();
        Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars() | WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout());

        int insetsWidth = 0;
        int insetsHeight = 0;
        if (insets != null) {
            insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left;
            insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom;
        }
        Size realSize = new Size(0, 0);
        if (metrics.getBounds() != null) {
            Rect bounds = metrics.getBounds();
            realSize = new Size(bounds.width() - insetsWidth, bounds.height() - insetsHeight);
        }
        usableWidth = realSize.getWidth();
        usableHeight = realSize.getHeight();
    } else {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        usableWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    }

    return wantWidth ? usableWidth : usableHeight;
}
```

how can i get the `Insets.right` and `Insets.left` right after the screen rotating ??

**Plus** 
I found some clues. please check these below.

1. when i start the app again, it gets correct values(width, height)
   but it couldn't when i start the app for the first time.
2. in the second time, i close the app and i touch home screen, and restart the app, it can't get correct width and height.
3. you can get correct width, height even though you close the app if you do not touch or drag your home screen.

so it operates weirdly.

Comment: Have you tried this in Android 13? I've made some code which is similar to yours, I'm encountering Insets.right and Insets.left randomly returns 0 on Android 12, but I'm not able to reproduce this issue on Android 13. Every time when I'm having this issue, a reboot fixes the issue. I suspect this is a bug in Android12, and I'm still looking for a workaround.

Comment: @LynchChen Hi Chen! at first, sorry, i didn't try it in Android 13. but i tested it in Android 12 and it worked well even though it was same device(but i updated the android os of the device from 11 to 12). So, i suspect that this issue has something to do with device. and what is your android studio version? when i tested it, My Android studio was arctic fox.

Comment: I'm using arctic fox too. Here's more detail about my issue. I'm also encountering this issue on real device(Oneplus OxygenOS 12) with compiled releases. First installation on the device has no problem, however if I install the same compiled apk to overwrite(update) the original installation, the bug appears. The problem can only be solved by a reboot. And I upgraded my Oneplus device to OxygenOS 13, this issue no longer exists on my Oneplus device.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit late to the party, but any have you eventually found the solution?